# Recursively search all directories that have one mp4 file whose size is less than 10MB

Tags: bash, shell-script

I am trying to recursively find all directories that have one mp4 file whose size is less than 10MB.

The conditions are ,

1. There must be only one mp4 file in the directory.
2. The mp4 file can not be more than 10MB.

The command I am using is

```
% find . -type f -name "*.mp4" -size -10M | cut -d/ -f2 | sort | uniq -c | grep "^      1"
```

I am not sure what is going on, but this command is not returning accurate result.

After further investigation I found that the following command works.

```
find . -type 'f' -name "*.mp4" -printf '%h\n' | sort | uniq -c | grep -E "\s+1\s"| cut -c 9-
```

But when I add `-size -10000000c` to the mix , it finds files that has one mp4 file which has size less than 10MB, but there are other mp4 files which have size greater than 10MB. I mean my mentioned command does not take into consideration the mp4 files which has size greater than 10MB. I think the problem in can be broken into two steps.

1. Find all directories that has one mp4 file. Which is done by the mentioned command.
2. Check if the files are less than 10MB.

I can get the file size of single mp4 files in a directory using.

```
find . -type 'f' -name "*.mp4" -printf '%h\n' | sort | uniq -c | grep -E "\s+1\s" | cut -c 9-| xargs -I {} -n 1 /usr/bin/du -a "{}" | grep -v ".mp4$"
```

Comment: What does that command return? And why isn't that accurate?

Comment: @Henriksupportsthecommunity i have updated the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With GNU `find` at least, `-size -10M` is true for files whose size rounded up to the next mebibyte is strictly less than 10, so 9 or less.

A file that is 9 x 1024 x 1024 + 1 = 9437185 byte large is not selected because that's rounded up to 10MiB so not < 10.

For files that are strictly smaller that 10MB (1 megabyte is 1,000,000 bytes, not to be confused with 1 mebibyte == 1,048,576 bytes), so sizes 0 to 9,999,999, use:

```
find . -size -10000000c
```

For files strictly smaller than 10MiB, so sizes from 0 to 10485759:

```
find . -size -10485760c
```

Now, to get the directories containing one and only one of those files, on a GNU system, you can do:

```
LC_ALL=C find . -name '*.mp4'  -type f -size -10000000c -printf '%h\0' |
  LC_ALL=C sort -z |
  LC_ALL=C uniq -zu |
  tr '\0' '\n'
```

Where

- `find` prints the `h`ead (dirname) of those files, NUL delimited (note the `LC_ALL=C` to report all filenames ending in `.mp4` even those whose name is otherwise not valid text in the current locale).
- `sort` sorts them for `uniq` (again, with `LC_ALL=C` to avoid problems with filenames that are not valid text in the locale, and other problems with characters with not completely defined order).
- `uniq -zu` reports only the unique ones.

The list of files is passed between those NUL delimited as NUL is the only character that cannot occur in a file path. We only convert those NULs to newline in the end with `tr` for human consumption.

With `zsh`, you could also do:

```
print -rC1 -- **/*(NFe['()(( $# == 1 )) $REPLY/*.mp4(N.L-10000000Y2)'])
```

Where:

- `print -rC1 --` `print`s its arguments `r`aw on `1` `C`olumn
- `**/` is any number of subdirectories.
- `*(NF...)` is any filename (excluding hidden ones) but further qualified by those `N`, `F`, `e`... glob qualifiers.
- `N`: enables `nullglob` for that glob so that it expands to nothing instead of returning an error if there's no match.
- `F`: selects `F`ull directories (directories with at least one entry other than `.` and `..`).
- `e[code]`: selects files for which the `code` is successful.
- `() {body} arguments` is an anonymous functions taking a number of arguments.
- The `{body}` here is the `(( $# == 1 ))` arithmetic evaluation that returns *true* if the number of arguments to that anonymous function is 1.
- `$REPLY` inside the `code` is the path to the file (here directory) being considered.
- `*.mp4(qualifiers)`: (non-hidden) `mp4` files further qualified.
- `.`: regular files only (like `find`'s `-type f`).
- `L-10000000`: files strictly smaller than 10MB.
- `Y2`: stop after finding 2 files as an optimisation.

Note that it doesn't consider `.` (the current working directory itself). If you want it to be considered, replace `**/*` with `{.,**/*}`.

---

Now, as you've now clarified, if you want to find directories that contain only one mp4 file, and that file be regular (not directory, symlink...) and be smaller than 10MB (so for instance exclude a dir that contains both a 5MB and 15MB mp4 file even though it only has one mp4 file less than 10MB on the ground that it has more than one mp4 in total regardless of size), still with `zsh`:

```
print -rC1 -- **/*(NFe['
    () {
      (( $# == 1 )) && ()(($#)) $1(N.L-10000000)
    } $REPLY/*.mp4(NY2)
  '])
```

With GNU `find` and GNU `awk` (or any awk that can deal with NUL-delimited records), that could be:

```
LC_ALL=C find . -name '*.mp4' -printf '%h\0%s\0%y\0' |
  awk -v RS='\0' '
   {
     getline size; getline type
     total[$0]++
     if (size < 10e6 && type == "f") found[$0]++
   }
   END {for (dir in found) if (total[dir] == 1) print dir}'
```

Comment: In both zsh and bash solutions, I am getting directories that has more than one mp4 files. The conditions are , 1. There must be only one mp4 file in the directory. 2. The mp4 file can not be more than 10MB.

Comment: the command `find . -type 'f' -name "*.mp4" -printf '%h\n' | sort | uniq -c | grep -E "\s+1\s"`  works. But when I add `-size -10000000c` to the mix , it finds files that has one mp4 file which has size less than 10MB, but there are other mp4 files which have size greater than 10MB. I mean my mentioned command does not take into consideration the mp4 files which has size greater than 10MB. I think I should break the problem in two steps. 1. Find all directories that has one mp4 file. Which is done by the mentioned command. 2. Check if the files are less than 10MB.

Comment: @blueray, see edit.

Answer (score 2):

`find` is great, and I use it all the time, for tasks much more complicated than this...but sometimes figuring out all of `find`'s options and getting it to do what you want and then using other programs like `sort`, `grep`, `uniq`, etc is a bit of a PITA and it seems simpler to just write your own custom tool to do exactly what you want in a language with a decent library for recursively searching directories, and do it with a decent editor rather than the shell's command-line editor.

So you end up writing yet another minor variation of something like the following.  Change the `wanted` subroutine, and you change what the `find` function discovers.  This one prints out a list of directories containing at least one regular file <= 10MiB in size, with a filename ending with `.mp4`:

```perl
$ cat find-mp4-1.pl 
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use File::Find;

my %found;

sub wanted {
  -f $_ && -s $_ <= 10485760 && /\.mp4\Z/s &&
    $found{$File::Find::dir . "/"}++;
};

# Search all directories listed on command line.
# Default to current directory
find(\&wanted, @ARGV ? @ARGV : '.');

print join("\n", sort keys %found), "\n" if %found;
```

I've written so many little `File::Find` scripts like this that I've lost count.

Sample run:

```
$ mkdir videos
$ touch video1.mp4 videos/video2.mp4
$ ./find-mp4-1.pl 
./
./videos/
```

And then you realise that it would sometimes be useful to have NUL-separated output, so it needs a `-0` option. And once that's done, think that being able to specify the required size on the command line would be nice, and ditto for the filename pattern to match, and an option for searching case-insensitively would be great, and so would being able to use "human-readable" sizes, and I could make it a little bit faster by pre-compiling the regex and matching only against the basename portion of the filename (who doesn't love a little bit of premature optimisation) and... you get carried away and do this:

```
$ cat find-mp4-2.pl
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use File::Find;
use Number::Bytes::Human qw(parse_bytes);
use Getopt::Std;

my %found;

my %opts;
$Getopt::Std::STANDARD_HELP_VERSION=1;
our $VERSION='0.2';
getopts('0:s:r:i',\%opts) ||
  die "Usage: $0 [-0] [-s size] [-r regex] [-i] [directory...]\n";

my $sep   = $opts{0} ? "\0" : "\n";
my $size  = $opts{s} // '10MiB';
my $regex = $opts{r} // '\.mp4\Z';

$size  = parse_bytes($size);

# pre-compile the regex: case insensitive or case sensitive?
$regex = $opts{i} ? qr/$regex/si : qr/$regex/s;

sub wanted {
  -f $_ && -s $_ <= $size && $File::Find::name =~ /$regex/ &&
    $found{$File::Find::dir . "/"}++;
};

find(\&wanted, @ARGV ? @ARGV : '.');

print join($sep, sort keys %found), $sep if %found;
```

Note: [File::Find](https://perldoc.perl.org/File::Find) and [Getopt::Std](https://perldoc.perl.org/Getopt::Std) are core perl modules and are included with perl.
[Number::Bytes::Human](https://metacpan.org/release/Number-Bytes-Human) is not, it needs to be installed separately (on Debian and derivatives: `sudo apt-get install libnumber-bytes-human-perl`. Other distros may have it packaged too.  Otherwise, install it with `cpan`).

Or just delete the `use Number::Bytes::Human qw(parse_bytes);` and `$size  = parse_bytes($size);` lines and specify file sizes in bytes like some primitive cave-person.

And then you think "hmmm...maybe I should have used [Getopt::Long](https://perldoc.perl.org/Getopt::Long) instead of `Getopt::Std` to be able to handle `--long` options too, and having a `-c` option to output the number of matches in a directory might be useful and it needs [documentation](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlpod) and ...".  Maybe you even start modifying it to do that before you realise, "No! This is **madness**.  Tool-making is fun, but enough is enough.".

You know, just as some hypothetical example of what someone crazy enough might do, not naming any names or anything. I can stop any time I want to. Where's my sponsor's phone number? I think I need to call them.

---

BTW, to print only the directories that contain **exactly** one matching video, you could change the `print join ...` line to:

```
  foreach (sort keys %found) {
    print "$d\n" if $found{$_} == 1
  };
```

(or `print "$d$sep" ...` for the second version)

Note that this would print directories that contained more than one .mp4 file where only one of them was <= 10MB.  To exclude those, you'd have to modify the `wanted` subroutine so that they never made it into the `%found` hash (or were deleted from it before the `find()` function finishes).  Maybe by using another hash to keep track of directories where more than one .mp4 file was found, something like:

```
sub wanted {
  next unless -f $_ && $File::Find::name =~ /\.mp4\Z/s;

  my $d = $File::Find::dir . '/';
  $seen{$d}++;

  if ($seen{$d} > 1) {
    delete $found{$d};
  } else {
    $found{$d} = 1 if -s $_ <= 10485760;
  }
};
```

and change the `my %found;` line to `my (%found, %seen);`